# Assembly obsfucation by dotfuscator

Tags: .net, dotfuscator

I have an application consist of various dll and one exe. In exe we have reference various dll say for example business logic dll , data access dll etc.

With dotfuscator we were able to obfuscate only exe part of application, if we try to obfuscate dll then they get obfuscated but application does not run.
But when only exe is obfuscated and dll does not obfuscated then application runs fine.

My query is that will application at later stage can give problem if we obfuscate one exe and not dll's?

Comment: why -1 whats wrong in this question?

Comment: The problem with the question: every obfuscation tool needs to be configured correctly. This is different for every tool and your question needs to be directed to the customer support for that tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... it should'nt be a problem if you app is well designed. I mean that it will works well if your exe references your DLLs but your DLLs don't have any reference to your exe project.

I recomend you to check [Eazfuscator.NET](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net), we're working with it in our company and we haven't any complaints. We ofuscate both DLLs and Exe projects.

Comment: Eazfuscator worked well for us as well. We investigated quite a few obfuscators.